# sending mails doesn't send to gmail sever

Tags: email, asp-classic

i am using the below code for sending mails in an asp page, but this code doesn't send to gmail server, does this server has a problem or i make an error in it?

```
<%Set myMail=CreateObject("CDO.Message")
myMail.Subject="Sending email with CDO"
myMail.From="mymail@mydomain.com"
myMail.To="someone@somedomain.com"
myMail.TextBody="This is a message."
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")=2
'Name or IP of remote SMTP server
 myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
 ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")=My SERVER
 myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport")=25 
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Update
myMail.Send
set myMail=nothing
%>
```

any help

Comment: When you say it doesn't send to gmail, is there a server error or do you just not receive the email. If you don't get an error but don't receive the email then most likely the problem is that gmail is rejecting or quarantining the email. Make sure that you have a domain SPF record that authorises this server to send email for your domain.

Answer (score 1):

Gmail SMTP doesn't use port 25, it uses port 587

You'll also probably need to authenticate with username and password

```
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1 
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") ="yourname@gmail.com"
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") ="yourpassword"
```

See this

http://powerasp.net/content/new/sending_email_cdosys.asp

Comment: Should i set the user name and password ? As the mails can be sent to yahoo mail server. What is the difference?  If  yes should it be gmail and its password?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you.  Are you saying you can't send outgoing emails via gmails smtp server, or are you saying you're sending through another smtp server and recipients with @gmail.com addresses aren't receiving them.  If the latter is true then are you getting any deliver failure reports (bounces)?

Answer (score 0):

Lets see did you:

1. enable IMAP or POP on your account with Gmail?
2. I do not see authentication set anywhere in your code.
3. get from Gmail exact server name and port to use with your specific account.

edited to confirm Lankymart comment.

Comment: It doesn't have to be IMAP you can set up to send to gmail using POP3.

Comment: Yes you can, but as per GMAIL HELP first you must enable POP or IMAP on your account.